# jenkins groovy form access properties of current object

Tags: plugins, groovy, jenkins

I have a Jenkins plugin where I am trying to show a repeatableProperty

```
namespace(lib.FormTagLib).with {
    entry{
        repeatableProperty(field: "FIELD", noAddButton: true, default:descriptor.loadDefaultItems())

    }
}
```

and then in the form for the FIELD

```
f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)

f.invisibleEntry{
   if(instance.readonly){
       f.textbox(field:"readonly",value:1)
    }
    if(instance.getReadonly() == false){
        f.textbox(field:"readonly",value:1)
    }
}
```

But instance is not defined. What would be the correct way to get at my readonly property or getReadonly() method?

update:

If I use 'it' this is the error

```
<d:invokeBody> Cannot get property 'readonly' on null object
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:100)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:234)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)...
```

Comment: I have no idea if this is right, but do you mean `if( it.readonly ){`?

Comment: The debugger reports 'it' as null (updated question with log) but thanks, I've been going round and round with it!